# Is there any harm if i shrink my WSS logging database inside my Dev machine

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, sharepoint, shrink

I know my question is about SharePoint, but it is a pure database question.

I am working on my SharePoint 2013 Dev machine, and i am running out of space, now i checked the WSS_Logging database inside my SharePoint database, and i find that it have 34% of its size as a free space :-

[image]

so is there any harm if i shrink it ,to save space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Dev machine, should be ok

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=400

I'd recommend backing up everything first, and remember, only for the Dev machine.

Comment: although i am not planning to do so on live,, but why shrinking a live database should be avoided ?

Comment: Forward planning for the most part. If you shrink a database that will need the space again, you're causing unnecessary disk i/o as it needs the space again

Comment: but general speaking most if the time shrinking the database will not cause data lost or other permanent problems.. is this correct ?

Comment: Just shrinking the database removes the empty space available.  The link provided guess goes beyond that, but just talking about shrinking.. It is generally considered bad practice unless the file has grown excessively large due to something like a large temporary import that has since been removed etc.   It shouldn't remove any data or cause issues except where you'd have to keep sizing back up.. And I'd always advise backing up before making any chances like that.